How to get position-bytes, aligned with file, despite DOS newlines?
I create this test file:
test_file.txt:
aaaa bbbb
aaaa bbbb
aaaa bbbb
aaaa bbbb
aaaa bbbb
aaaa bbbb
cccc.dddd

I put point on the . in cccc.dddd and call (position-bytes (point)). It says 65. But if I open the file with hexl-find-file I can see that the . character is actually at byte index 0x46 (70). I know point positions start at 1, so I want position-bytes to return 71. I think the difference is because of the DOS newlines in the file (\r\n, 0x0d0a). I'm guessing Emacs has some internal buffer where those are just \n (0x0a)
Is there a way to make position-bytes report the byte position in the file? Or is there another function I can call to get the byte position in the file?
I'm using Emacs on Windows: M-x version => GNU Emacs 29.2 (build 2, x86_64-w64-mingw32) of 2024-02-01
(Not sure how to tag this question.)

In case it helps, find-file-literally avoids that (but I suspect that's not going to be useful.)  I don't have a more helpful suggestion.

https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

@phils: I think find-file-literally is exactly the answer: it's the only way to be sure that the buffer is an exact copy of the bytes on disk, no? Why do you think it's not going to be useful?

NickD: Only because I'm imagining the question was prompted by a requirement to map positions between a file and a buffer which is being used to edit that file, and one wouldn't normally visit a file literally in order to edit it.  I may be reading too much into the question, though.

The find-file-literally function may help. My situation is I have a file of code, in a custom language, for which I've written a parser and interpreter. When there is an error, I'm reporting utf-8 byte offsets, and they don't line up with emacs point positions.

@phils was imagining correctly :-) Maybe you can maintain not only  a byte offset in your parser but also a (line-number offset-in-line) pair and use the latter for setting the position in an Emacs buffer?
